# Vectors: Two Lines, Need Explanation

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having some trouble understanding what a few lines mean in a code. I recently started learning C++ and picked up Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++." There is a question in chapter 4 that was tripping me up, so I searched for a solution online to reference. Here is the code I ended up using in conjunction with the book:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
vector<double> temps;
for (double temp; cin >> temp;)
    temps.push_back(temp);

double sum = 0;
for (double x : temps) sum += x;
cout << "Average Temperature: " << sum / temps.size() << "\n";

if (temps.size() %2==0) {
    sort(temps);
    cout << "Median Temperature: " << (temps[temps.size() / 2 - 1] + temps[temps.size() / 2]) / 2 << "\n"; //line one
} else {
    sort(temps);
    cout << "Median Temperature: " << temps[temps.size() / 2] << "\n"; //line two
}

keep_window_open();
return 0;
}
```

I commented on the lines that I don't understand. What exactly is happening with these vectors? I understand that "temps.size()" is used to call upon the elements within a vector and that usually the "-1" means to take the last value. However, when I try and think this through in my head, it just doesn't make sense in conjunction to the outputs. Yes, the output is correct in the code, but could someone please help explain those lines to me? I simply don't want to just copy and paste code and not understand it. I need help understanding at a basic level how the code is being outputted correctly so that I can make my own solution. Thanks!

Comment: just add breakpoints to those lines and debug you will understand

Comment: Is there implementation of  sort(temps); ?? or you wanted to use  sort(temps.begin(),temps.end());

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm not sure how to do this but I'll find out how!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I do know that in the header file there is a line with this:  std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());

Comment: `and that usually the "-1" means to take the last value` No, this is not the case in C++. Maybe in some other languages.

Comment: More than programming its math to understand what is the median  temperatur e https://www.eduplace.com/math/mw/background/4/09/te_4_09_mean_ideas.html

Comment: Line one means if you have even number of elements in the temp vector then the median is the average of (n/2-1)th & (n/2)th elements. 
Line two means, you have odd number of elements in the temp vector. So according to the definition of `median` the (n/2)th element is the median.

Comment: Why do you think printed values are correct? What did you compare them against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The median of a data set is the value for which half the data is above the median and half the data is below the median. If there is an odd number of data points, it is the value of the middle data point. If there are an even number of data points, it is the arithmetic mean of the two central data points.

The if statement before line 1 checks if there is an even or an odd number of data points. If the comparison is true, there are an even number of data points, and therefore you need to take the average of the `temps[temps.size()/2-1]` (which is the maximum value under the median) and `temps[temps.size()/2]` (which is the minimum value over the median). If the comparison is false, then there are an odd number of elements, and therefore the median is the middle element `temps[temps.size()/2]`.

Comment: Much appreciated, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well it comes mathematics: [Median definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Finite_set_of_numbers). So, the code just follows the definition.

> I understand that "temps.size()" is used to call upon the elements within a vector and that usually the "-1" means to take the last value. However, when I try and think this through in my head, it just doesn't make sense in conjunction to the outputs.

No, here, it takes `temps.size()/2 -1`, the middle element of vector, not the last.